# tag <li> com elemento fantasma ou duplicado quando consome alguma API, como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, api

Pessoal primeiramente criei uma API utilizando NODE JS e estou consumindo ela no front-end. Eu consigo obter a informação no HTML, mas não do jeito que eu gostaria. Eu ja tentei com outras API's mais comuns como a POKE API para ver se o problema era a API, mas **o problema em si é que ela continua mostrando um elemento "-li-" a mais, como se houvesse outro item dentro do objeto**.

O resultado na página é o seguinte:

**VEJAM A IMAGEM:**

**[IMAGEM DA PÁGINA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZlF0.png)**

o HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main></main>
    <ul></ul>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O Script:

```
    try {
        const resposta = await fetch( 'http://localhost:4567/')
        const data = await resposta.json()
        
        Show(data)
        console.log(data)
    }catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
                     
            
const Show = (users) =>{
    let output = ''
    
    for( let user of users){
        output += `<li>${user.name}<li>` 
    }

    document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = (output)
}


getContent()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Opa, faltou só fechar a tag li

```js
for( let user of users){
        output += `<li>${user.name}</li>` 
    }
```